# android - new app version after package rename

Tags: android, android-studio, package

I have retroactively renamed my packages in an Android Studio project. If I now build and install my app on a device, a second app is created in addition to the already existing app with the old package names. I have already generated some data on the first version of the app, that I would like to keep. Is there a way to just update the first version as usual instead of creating this alternate version?

Thanks

Comment: Why you changed package name? Didn't upgrading `versionCode` and `versionName` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have just to update version code and version name in gradle, so the first version will be updated and you will keep your data

Comment: Sadly changing the version name/code does not solve the problem.

Comment: Strange, if you keep the old package name and just updating version name/code normally it would work